# How I can avoid parallax performance problems?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, scroll, parallax

I try to create parallax-effect, but have serious performance problems in Edge and Safari. Somebody please tell me, how I can avoid this problems?

Example: https://github.com/bashkos/Problem-parallax

Comment: Just google for `webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` it solves usually the problems..

Comment: @Hardy Thank you for response, but it not helpful in this case

Answer (score 2):

Use [`transform: translate( ... )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead of setting `bottom` and co. Setting `transform` helps because browsers then render a new drawing layer which gets separated from the rest.

Also it seems to be better to use `position: fixed` and calculate all values around that fact, since the image is at the same position all the time no matter of the current scroll position. That of course means that you also need to know when to make it visible.

*Sidenote:* I guess you meant `resize` in `window.addEventListener('recise', ...)`

Comment: Already use it https://github.com/bashkos/Problem-parallax/blob/master/assets/script.js#L24

Comment: Ah sorry, I only saw the `bottom` line. Let me check again

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. When I buildt my last parallax site, I had the same problem. What I did was to use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` since it is at the very same position all the time. Of course that makes your calculations a bit trickier I guess

Comment: It also presupposes specific layout markup, that may be complicated for content website

Comment: with `position: fixed` I have vsync problems, I see white stripes sometimes